# Uber Rider hangs on launch

Tags: applications, cyanogenmod

I am running Cyanogenmod 12.1 on a Nexus 5. It include SE-Linux in enforcing mode and Privacy Guard. Cyanogenmod does not provide a store, so I fetched Uber from Google Play using a [download service](http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/) and installed it via the command line with `adb install com.ubercab.apk`.

When I attempt to launch Uber, it simply hangs. The screen capture is below.

When I inspect the `logcat` logs, it shows some minor issues. It looks like the app is not as tested as well as it could be, but I don't see any fatal exceptions. The output is below.

Its also worth noting other apps, such as Textra and Firefox, run fine when installed the same way.

How do I run Uber Rider on this Cyanogenmod/Nexus combination?

---

```
I/ActivityManager(  746): Start proc 3207:com.ubercab/u0a18 for activity com.ube
rcab/.UBUberActivity
I/MultiDex( 3207): VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
I/MultiDex( 3207): install
I/MultiDex( 3207): VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled
.
W/ActivityManager(  746): getRunningAppProcesses: caller 10018 does not hold REA
L_GET_TASKS; limiting output
I/Fabric  ( 3207): Initializing Crashlytics 2.2.3.41
W/ActivityManager(  746): getRunningAppProcesses: caller 10018 does not hold REA
L_GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  746): getRunningAppProcesses: caller 10018 does not hold REA
L_GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/Settings( 3207): Setting install_non_market_apps has moved from android.provid
er.Settings.Global to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only valu
e.
W/Settings( 3207): Setting install_non_market_apps has moved from android.provid
er.Settings.Global to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only valu
e.
W/Settings( 3207): Setting install_non_market_apps has moved from android.provid
er.Settings.Global to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only valu
e.
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3207): Google Play services is missing.
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3207): Google Play services is missing.
I/art     ( 3207): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1582(96KB)
AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 36% free, 27MB/43MB, paused 7.948ms total
 31.274ms
F/Adjust  ( 3207): PRODUCTION: Adjust is running in Production mode. Use this se
tting only for the build that you want to publish. Set the environment to `sandb
ox` if you want to test your app!
D/OpenGLRenderer( 3207): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
E/ActivityThread( 3207): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.pr
ovider.AttributionIdProvider
D/Atlas   ( 3207): Validating map...
V/WindowManager(  746): Adding window Window{30dc474e u0 com.ubercab/com.ubercab
.UBUberActivity} at 3 of 9 (before Window{adeae23 u0 Starting com.ubercab})
I/Adjust  ( 3207): Unable to get Google Play Services Advertising ID at start ti
me
I/Adjust  ( 3207): Started subsession 3 of session 1
I/WebViewFactory( 3207): Loading com.android.webview version 39 (1636aa03d7-arm)
 (code 300001)
I/LibraryLoader( 3207): Time to load native libraries: 101 ms (timestamps 1997-2
098)
I/LibraryLoader( 3207): Expected native library version number "",actual native
library version number ""
V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider( 3207): Binding Chromium to main looper Looper
(main, tid 1) {2650a87f}
I/LibraryLoader( 3207): Expected native library version number "",actual native
library version number ""
I/chromium( 3207): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(104)] Chromium logging enabled:
 level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I/BrowserStartupController( 3207): Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=
true
W/art     ( 3207): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring

W/chromium( 3207): [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(304)] locale_file_path.empty()
I/chromium( 3207): [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(65)] Load from apk succesful,
fd=57 off=46184 len=3037
I/chromium( 3207): [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(78)] Loading webviewchromium.p
ak from, fd:58 off:229484 len:1089587
W/AudioManagerAndroid( 3207): Requires BLUETOOTH permission
I/Adreno-EGL( 3207): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 01/14/15, a
b0075f, Id3510ff6dc
W/chromium( 3207): [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_settings.cc(331)] SPDY proxy OF
F at startup
W/art     ( 3207): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring

W/AwContents( 3207): onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring

W/ScreenOrientationListener( 3207): Removing an inexistent observer!
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3207): Google Play services is missing.
I/Timeline( 3207): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.ubercab time:652225
I/ActivityManager(  746): START u0 {cmp=com.ubercab/.webclient.app.WebClientActi
vity} from uid 10018 on display 0
V/WindowManager(  746): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{35bf0ab2 token=Token{64a44bd
 ActivityRecord{7734414 u0 com.ubercab/.webclient.app.WebClientActivity t4}}} to
 stack=1 task=4 at 1
V/WindowManager(  746): Adding window Window{adeae23 u0 Starting com.ubercab} at
 4 of 9 (after Window{30dc474e u0 com.ubercab/com.ubercab.UBUberActivity})
I/OpenGLRenderer( 3207): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer( 3207): Enabling debug mode 0
W/art     ( 3207): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring

W/AwContents( 3207): onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring

W/art     ( 3207): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring

W/art     ( 3207): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring

V/WindowManager(  746): Adding window Window{2a8f1ffe u0 com.ubercab/com.ubercab
.webclient.app.WebClientActivity} at 4 of 10 (before Window{adeae23 u0 Starting
com.ubercab})
I/Timeline( 3207): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@28cd19b0 t
ime:652505
I/ActivityManager(  746): Displayed com.ubercab/.webclient.app.WebClientActivity
: +248ms (total +1s663ms)
I/Timeline(  746): Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{7734414
 u0 com.ubercab/.webclient.app.WebClientActivity t4} time:652509
I/chromium( 3207): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: Uber is not defin
ed", source:  (1)
CTRL+C
```

---

[image]

Comment: `Google Play services is missing.` is probably the cause. It likely requires this to be installed in order to function

Answer (score 1):

You most probably need GApps for it to work properly.
https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps

Comment: Thanks Divulged. Are there other options? I run Cyanogenmod to distance myself from folks like Google. Sorry to have to aks. [Uber Support](https://help.uber.com/) sucks. They don't allow searching for terms like Cyanogenmod (nothing happens when pressing `ENTER`) and they don't provide support contacts (no email address or web based support form).

Comment: @jww Unable to get Google Play Services Advertising ID at start ti
me ------ That definitely implies, as far as I can see, that Uber's application has google play services as a dependency. In which case its never going to work without it (if it is indeed a dependency for the app), unfortunately.